# InvertRect equivalent in C#/.NET

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, gdi

Is there some equivalent for `InvertRect` function in C#/.NET?
(For using with WinForms.)

- I know that I can use `InvertRect` directly using `DllImport`. But I'm curious about whether there is more proper equivalent.
- I know that there is `System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle(Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor)` function. But somewhy (unlike most of other `ControlPaint` functions) it doesn't accept `Graphics graphics` and draws rectangle directly on the screen (**WTF??? Why?!!**).

Comment: InvertRect() dates from Windows version 1.  It stopped being useful a long time ago, the color you get on a modern machine is wildly unrelated to the original color of the rectangle.  FillReversibleRectangle() offers an equivalent that at least gives you *some* control over the resulting colors.  It operates directly on the video adapter's frame buffer, you'd only ever consider calling such a function to make it fast.  Painting is fast enough today to not need these kind of hacks anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant, `InvertRect`, `DrawFocusRect` and similar functions are useful because they XOR colors when modifying pixels. So their effect is reversible: i.e. if focus rectangle is drawn on something, it can be easily "un-drawn" by just one call to DrawFocusRect with no need to invalidate/repaint that thing. (Please, tell me if I'm wrong.)